# using robot class how can save image?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I trying using robot class for saving image...but it not properly working.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://agiletesters.com.br");
     Robot rb =new Robot();
     rb.mouseMove(270, 160);
     rb.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
     rb.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);

     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
     Thread.sleep(11000);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

in this right click is working but it not selecting 'Save image as...' option.

I tried this but download image  is not showing:-

```
try {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.get("http://agiletesters.com.br");
         System.setProperty("http.agent", "Firefox");
         WebElement logo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"header-menu\"]/div/div[1]/a/img"));
         String logoSRC = logo.getAttribute("src");

         URL imageURL = new URL(logoSRC);
         BufferedImage saveImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL.openStream());

         ImageIO.write(saveImage, "png", new File("logo-forum.png"));

         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
            driver.close();
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that your `BufferedImage saveImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL.openStream());` is failing due to missing [Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

The correct way of downloading file is:

1. Obtaining current set of cookies from the Firefox browser instance using [`driver.managet().getCookies()` function](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies)
2. Use underlying [OKHTTP library to execute the GET request](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html) for the logo and save the file.

Example code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();

Request request = new Request.Builder().url(logoSRC).addHeader("Cookie", cookies.toString()).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

File downloadedLogo = new File("logo-forum.png");
BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(downloadedLogo));
sink.writeAll(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).source());
sink.close();
```